# Using jQuery.parseXML

Tags: jquery, xml, xml-parsing, rss, parsexml

I am trying to create an aggregator that will pull items from an RSS feed and store them in a jQuery array (so that I can cycle through the array and randomise output).

I have found some info on using `jQuery.parseXML` for this however the demo provided I cannot figure out as I don't have much knowledge in the area and the demo doesn't show anywhere where the link to the RSS feed is added?

```
<p id="someElement"></p>
<p id="anotherElement"></p>

<script>
var xml = "<rss version='2.0'><channel><title>RSS Title</title></channel></rss>",
  xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
  $xml = $( xmlDoc ),
  $title = $xml.find( "title" );

// Append "RSS Title" to #someElement
$( "#someElement" ).append( $title.text() );

// Change the title to "XML Title"
$title.text( "XML Title" );

// Append "XML Title" to #anotherElement
$( "#anotherElement" ).append( $title.text() );
</script>
```

Where do I add my RSS feed link? And where is the array made?

Ultimately this will be a mosaic wall with all the items output visually in HTML.

The data I have from the RSS feed for each item is:

- title
- description
- link
- published date
- category

I need to pull all this data through so I can  output title, description, wrap the two in the link tag, and then store the category and use the stored publish date to randomise output (select last 30 days for example and output those items in a random order).

Here is the code I have written using the Ajax page but I don't know if that's right or what it should do to work....

```
jquery.ajax(http://www.sagittarius-digital.com/news.rss [, dataType xml])
```

Comment: you will need to use an [ajax request](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: @ArunPJohny thanks, I'll have a look. I just don't really know where to start or what bit to do first.

Comment: go through the doc first... can you share the rss feed url

Comment: I've read through it but there are no exmaples of how to actually write such code. Our XML file is http://www.sagittarius-digital.com/news.rss - This just needs to output as a UL LI or something similar for now, individual UL for each item and LI with the data in.

Comment: whether the page where the script will running will be within the domain http://www.sagittarius-digital.com/

Comment: if the domains are different then you will have to worry about same origin policy... locally do you have a web server or you are working with local filesystem

Comment: I have uploaded to a server: http://www.sagittarius-digital.com/sag-aggregator/sag-aggregator.html but it doesn't work regardless of whether I do news.rss OR link to the actual RSS feed neither of them work or do anything I just get a blank page.

Comment: see http://plnkr.co/edit/MduavW01LhyFDZKQQ1Al?p=preview

Comment: @ArunPJohny doesn't seem to work: http://www.sagittarius-digital.com/sag-aggregator/sag-aggregator.html

Comment: you need to give the complete url...

Comment: in your case http://www.sagittarius-digital.com/news.rss - in my case I used a relative path since both the html and the xml was in the same path

Comment: see the updated version at http://plnkr.co/edit/MduavW01LhyFDZKQQ1Al?p=preview also your xml is very big so it is taking a lot of time to load... can you try with a smaller xml file

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use $.parseXml() when you call the rss feed via ajax with a dataType of 'xml'.

```
$.ajax({
    url:'news.rss',
    dataType:'xml',
    success:function( xmlString ){
        var $xml = $( xmlDoc ),
        $title = $xml.find( "title" );

        $title.each(function(){
            console.log($(this).text());
        });
    }
});
```

Remember the RSS url needs to be in the same domain the javascript file is in. If not, then you will need to do some server-side logic, cURL for example, to get the rss feed.

Comment: Where does the link go? I don't understand where the link is supposed to go.

Comment: No the javascript is nowhere as I am working locally. Can I link if I link directly to sagittarius-digital.com - or must it be downloaded for example as news.xml for the time being?

Comment: I have tried with your updated code using the link but there doesn't seem to be anything showing up in the HTML file.

Comment: You will need to download and save the rss feed locally. Then change the url to the local file. Are you familiar with how to use cURL on the server?

Comment: I do not know what cURL is. I have uploaded it to the server anyway: http://www.sagittarius-digital.com/sag-aggregator/sag-aggregator.html - but if I can work locally it would be easier.

Comment: I would save an RSS file locally while you develop and test. You can change the URL when you go live. Unless the location of news.rss is in the same relative position on the production server as locally.

Comment: I have created a file locally but it does nothing as well. Neither live on server or with news.rss works.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44339/discussion-between-nick-johnson-and-francesca)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
  jQuery(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: 'news.rss', //place the your rss feed url here
      dataType: 'xml'
    }).done(function(xml){
      var items = $(xml).find('item').map(function(){
        var $item = $(this);
        var array = ['<li>'];
        array.push('<a href="' + $.trim($item.find('link').text()) + '">')
        array.push('<h3>' + $item.find('title').text() + '</h3>')
        array.push('</a>');
        array.push('<p>' + $item.find('description').text() + '</p>');
        array.push('<span class="category">' + $item.find('category').text() + '</span>')
        array.push('<span class="pub-date">' + $item.find('pubDate').text() + '</span>')
        array.push('</li>');
        return array
      }).get();
      $('ul').append(items.join(' '));
    }).fail(function(){
      conole.log('error', arguments)
    })
  })
```

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/MduavW01LhyFDZKQQ1Al?p=preview)